# multi page form. where do I save the previous data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I have a 7 step form, which will have the ability to go the the previous steps. using mvc, is it best to create one large view model and have the 7 steps all in one page, but only displaying certain sections? Or should I divide it up between pages/views?

Comment: That depends on what you are modeling, this is a very User focused question. What would be best for your user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will be a good choice for saving the previous page's data.

For example,

### Page 1

```
var customer = new Customer
{
  FirstName = "John",
};    
Session["Customer"] = customer;
```

### Page 2

```
var customer = Session["Customer"];
customer.Address1 = "123 Street";
Session["Customer"] = customer;
```

Comment: Would storing the data in a cookie instead of a session provide any benefits/drawbacks?

Comment: I'll not do that in your scenario mainly for security reason. Besides, cookie is limited to 4KB *(it will slow down your page if you save a lot of stuffs in cookies)* and only allows to store string value.

Comment: Actually, SessionState uses cookie too (unless you explicitly set in web.config). It just stores the SessionId in cookie and the actual data at Server's Memory.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you save the data in Model part of your MVC.  Break your form up so that it is easiest to understand and process from the users point of view.  Once they are done with the form you can send your data in your Model over to the server to be processed. Or you can allow them to make changes as needed.

If your data structure is complex then you make a Model that represents it as best as possible, it will be easier to handle then.

Comment: How did you save the data to the model when going to a new page?

Comment: Use the "Next" button or what ever you have to change forms and set an event on it that takes all the form data and stores it in the model.  Each MVC has a different way of doing this.  You may also want to consider a completely JavaScript based MVC that keeps the Model in the browser until you want to send to the server.  For example Backbone.js or Angular.js.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a 12-page form before in ASP.NET MVC. Each page of the form was long and I stored data after each page's submission. 
I had a separate table (model class) for each page and a corresponding view model for each view. When you navigate back to some previous page you simply retrieve data for that page.

I was also storing the last completed page number in a database for navigation purposes. Users could log out and come back later to finish the form and they would be redirected to the page where they left off.

Comment: I really like your idea in your last paragraph, keeping the page number.